# Chainstate LevelDB corruption after reading from the database

Tags: bitcoind, python, leveldb

I've been working with the LevelDB for a few weeks, coding some tools to access the database and parse the data to be human readable.

However, every single time I read from the chainstate the data gets corrupted (ask me to rebuild it when running bitcoind). I decided to copy the DB as a workaround after it happened the first time, but it's quite annoying to do so every single time I want to update the data.

I'm using plyvel and Python 2.8, and I close the DB every time I finish with the reading.

**Example**

```
# Open the LevelDB
db = plyvel.DB(".bitcoin/chainstate")

for key, o_value in db:
 # do stuff

# Close the LevelDB
db.close()
```

Does anyone knows what could be the reason? Does bitcoind prevent other software to access the DB by marking the last access somehow?

**chainstate LOG** after running the code, retrieving the obfuscation key, and closing the database:

```
2017/03/22-11:03:45.746702 7f3c18a39700 Recovering log #394423
2017/03/22-11:03:45.854583 7f3c18a39700 Delete type=0 #394423
2017/03/22-11:03:45.854711 7f3c18a39700 Delete type=3 #394422
```

**Example code**:

```
db = plyvel.DB(".bitcoin/chainstate")
o_key = db.get((a2b_hex("0e00") + "obfuscate_key"))
db.close()
```

**debug.log** after opening bitcoind (just the part referring to the LevelDB):

```
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Cache configuration:
2017-03-22 10:03:45 * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2017-03-22 10:03:45 * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2017-03-22 10:03:45 * Using 290.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set
2017-03-22 10:03:45 init message: Loading block index...
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Opening LevelDB in /home/sdelgado/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Opened LevelDB successfully
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Using obfuscation key for /home/sdelgado/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Opening LevelDB in /home/sdelgado/.bitcoin/chainstate
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Opened LevelDB successfully
2017-03-22 10:03:45 Using obfuscation key for /home/sdelgado/.bitcoin/chainstate: 27c78118b7316105
2017-03-22 10:03:48 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 810
2017-03-22 10:03:48 LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=53, size=51783543, heights=457770...458279, time=2017-03-18...2017-03-21)
2017-03-22 10:03:48 Checking all blk files are present...
2017-03-22 10:03:49 LoadBlockIndexDB: transaction index disabled
2017-03-22 10:03:49 LevelDB read failure: Corruption: corrupted compressed block contents
2017-03-22 10:03:49 Corruption: corrupted compressed block contents
2017-03-22 10:03:51 Aborted block database rebuild. Exiting.
2017-03-22 10:03:51 scheduler thread interrupt
2017-03-22 10:03:51 Shutdown: In progress...
2017-03-22 10:03:51 StopNode()
2017-03-22 10:03:51 Shutdown: done
```

Comment: Are you opening the database while bitcoind is running?

Comment: No, bitcoind is not running when I'm opening the database.

Comment: Then I have no clue. Can you share your debug.log or your chainstate/LOG file?

Comment: Updated with the logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plyvel has Snappy compression [enabled by default](https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#DB). Have you tried disabling it when opening the database?

```
# Open the LevelDB
db = plyvel.DB(".bitcoin/chainstate", compression=None)
```

With this code my bitcoind does not seem to complain after having opened the database with python.

Comment: That's seems to be the problem. No data corruption after opening it using compression=None. Thanks!